# cd autocomplete displays tons of info

Tags: command-line, 19.04

I use a lot of folders to organize my classes in school and often I simply have a folder inside another one all by itself as I know in the future I'll add more. For example Folder0 -> Folder1 by itself -> multiples files.

My question is when I do `cd`then try to autocomplete with Tab in my shells with nothing behind it, it shows me a lot more than expected and as such doesn't directly work, as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

Is this normal ? If yes how can I disable it so I can autocomplete directly into my unique folder ?

Thanks already

EDIT :
Here's the content of my ~/.bashrc file. I use Terminator with Bash-it a simple framework :

```
cat ~/.bashrc
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Path to the bash it configuration
export BASH_IT="/home/samuel/.bash_it"

# Lock and Load a custom theme file.
# Leave empty to disable theming.
# location /.bash_it/themes/
export BASH_IT_THEME='bakke'

# (Advanced): Change this to the name of your remote repo if you
# cloned bash-it with a remote other than origin such as `bash-it`.
# export BASH_IT_REMOTE='bash-it'

# Your place for hosting Git repos. I use this for private repos.
export GIT_HOSTING='git@git.domain.com'

# Don't check mail when opening terminal.
unset MAILCHECK

# Change this to your console based IRC client of choice.
export IRC_CLIENT='irssi'

# Set this to the command you use for todo.txt-cli
export TODO="t"

# Set this to false to turn off version control status checking within the prompt for all themes
export SCM_CHECK=true

# Set Xterm/screen/Tmux title with only a short hostname.
# Uncomment this (or set SHORT_HOSTNAME to something else),
# Will otherwise fall back on $HOSTNAME.
#export SHORT_HOSTNAME=$(hostname -s)

# Set Xterm/screen/Tmux title with only a short username.
# Uncomment this (or set SHORT_USER to something else),
# Will otherwise fall back on $USER.
#export SHORT_USER=${USER:0:8}

# Set Xterm/screen/Tmux title with shortened command and directory.
# Uncomment this to set.
#export SHORT_TERM_LINE=true

# Set vcprompt executable path for scm advance info in prompt (demula theme)
# https://github.com/djl/vcprompt
#export VCPROMPT_EXECUTABLE=~/.vcprompt/bin/vcprompt

# (Advanced): Uncomment this to make Bash-it reload itself automatically
# after enabling or disabling aliases, plugins, and completions.
# export BASH_IT_AUTOMATIC_RELOAD_AFTER_CONFIG_CHANGE=1

# Uncomment this to make Bash-it create alias reload.
# export BASH_IT_RELOAD_LEGACY=1

export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

# Nodejs
VERSION=v10.16.3
DISTRO=linux-x64
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATH



#aliases
alias upgradeall='sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade'
alias open='xdg-open'

# Load Bash It
source "$BASH_IT"/bash_it.sh




# pip bash completion start
_pip_completion()
{
    COMPREPLY=( $( COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
                   COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
                   PIP_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 $1 ) )
}
complete -o default -F _pip_completion pip
# pip bash completion end
```

Comment: IMHO it is not normal - in fact it looks more like the output of `compgen -v` than `compgen -f`

Comment: what shell are you using? please post the contents of `~/.(SHELL)rc`

Comment: @steeldriver I didn't know about this command but you are exactly right when I do a compgen -v this is the same output

Comment: @j-money I've edited my post so there are more infos

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171489/shell-display-all-2588-possibilities/171494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long researchs I finally found the answer. If you use Bash-It as your SHELL, make sure to disable system completion with `bash-it disable completion system`.

Then of course do reload your bash and your completion will work just fine without showing the whole output of `compgen-v`.